# Showing convergence of conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\big(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P} \big)$ be a probability space, and $\big(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ such that 
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(E_n \mid Y \big) \underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\quad \text{a.s}
$$
where $E_n$'s depend on the variable $Y$. I want to prove that
$$
\mathbb{P}(E_n) \underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\quad \text{a.s}
$$
But I have no idea how to begin. Thank you for any comment or suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Set

$$u_n(\omega) := \mathbb{P}(E_n \mid Y)(\omega).$$

Then, by assumption, $u_n \to 0$ almost surely. Moreover, $|u_n| \leq 1 \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$.  By the tower property, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(E_n) = \mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbb{P}(E_n \mid Y) \big]  = \mathbb{E}(u_n)$$

and by applying the dominated convergence theorem we obtain

$$\mathbb{P}(E_n) = \mathbb{E}(u_n) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0.$$